# Backbone collection inherit parent, Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

We're running into trouble with inheritance

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function() {
    this.tables = new MyOtherCollection();
    this.tables.parent = this;
}
});
```

Other examples we see where this breaks use super, but we've not defined that anywhere but when we run

```
MyModel.fetch()
```

we get

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: From the code and explanation you've posted it's not clear what the problem could be. Please elaborate on the problem, perhaps adding other relevant code.

Comment: What does `MyOtherCollection` do with its `parent` property? What does `MyModel` do with its `tables` property?